# Access SimpleXMLElement properties without looping

Tags: php, object, simplexml, tree-traversal

I've tried both the SimpleXMLElement XPath approach as well as the DOMDocument XPath approach, but cannot seem to get things straight either way, but at least with the SimpleXMLElement route, I could actually print out the results var and see what's going on. (See Results Below)

I want to use XPath querys without having to loop through the results. I guess I just want to access the results like an array, but the issue seems to be getting past the SimpleXMLElement objects within that results array.

I'm querying an HTML snippet by div with a specific class. There are several divs of this particular class though, so all of them are being returned, which is fine. That's what I want. But now I want to access each and get their values, only they have child divs in most cases.

Here's the line I'm using to execute the XPath query:

```
$stats = $xml->xpath("//div[contains(@class,'line-item')]");
```

Here's a print_r() output of the results:

```
// Output of $stats
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [class] => line-item
                )
            [div] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Total items shipped
                    [1] => 50
                )
        )
    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [class] => line-item-total
                )
            [div] => Array
                (
                    [0] => TOTAL EARNINGS *
                    [1] => $267.23
                )
        )
    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [class] => line-item-links
                )
            [a] => View full report
        )
    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [class] => line-item
                )
            [div] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Ordered items
                    [1] => 42
                )
        )
    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [class] => line-item
                )
            [div] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Clicks
                    [1] => 428
                )

        )
    [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [class] => line-item
                )
            [div] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Conversion
                    [1] => 9.81%
                )
        )
    [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [class] => line-item-links
                )
            [a] => View full report
        )
)
```

Now, since I know where each value is, I thought I could just access them like so:

```
$y['clicks'] = "{$stats[4]['div'][0]}: {$stats[5]['div'][1]}\n";
$y['ordered'] = "{$stats[3]['div'][0]}: {$stats[4]['div'][1]}\n";
$y['shipped'] = "{$stats[0]['div'][0]}: {$stats[0]['div'][1]}\n";
$y['conversion'] = "{$stats[5]['div'][0]}: {$stats[6]['div'][1]}\n"; // Doesn't work
$y['rate'] = "{$stats[1]['div'][0]}: {$stats[4]['div'][1]}\n"; // Neither encased in {}
$y['total'] = 'Yesterday\'s Earnings: '.$stats[1]['div'][1]."\n"; // Nor as concatenated
```

The obvious problem is the SimpleXMLElement object wedged in between the items in the $stats array and the ['div'] array whose sub-items' values I'm after, which are hiding behind those SimpleXMLElement objects.

So how would I get at those values beyond the SimpleXMLElement objects, without looping through the $stats array? Anything similar to what I've already tried above?

Comment: Do not use `print_r()`. Do not post the output of `print_r()`. Post the source XML, what you want to do and how you're trying to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're accessing stuff like `$stats[4]['div'][0]`. Array notation is for attributes. Please post your XML and never ever ever rely on `print_r()` when using SimpleXML.

I guess that what you want to use is `$stats[4]->div` although I have no idea what that `[0]` is for. I assume you've randomly tried to add `[0]` because of something you saw using `print_r()`, which is incorrect. Do not use `print_r()` when dealing with SimpleXML. Do not consider SimpleXML as objects and arrays, they're just ways to access **XML**. What's important is your XML. SimpleXML uses the familiar object syntax and array syntax, but don't think of it as a collection of objects and arrays, because it's not.

Comment: You're right Josh. This ended up being the issue. I was relying on print_r() when I should have just tried saving. The $stats[4]->div[0] syntax did the trick.

Comment: BTW, in the example above (yes, the print_r() output, I know...) $stats[4]->div[0] == 'Clicks' ...so I guess the print_r() output isn't completely evil. Just 98%. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use xpath queries to get all of these values separately?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a lot slower?

Comment: Possibly. But it depends on how often your script will be doing this and even then, do benchmark different approaches, either with microtime(), xhprof, xdebug or something else. The loss in performance may be very small and cleaner code may well be worth it.